# We need to be [packing] these questions into a more specific tag

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag [packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packing) should be renamed to something more specific, and the questions within it should be checked as to whether it's in the correct tag.

The wiki for [packing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/packing/info) says

> Use this tag for questions related to packing, which can extend from struct packing to grouping elements together.
>
> In C, packing will prevent the compiler from adding padding to a struct, which will save some memory, but may affect access speed to the members of the struct (since it may not memory-aligned).
>
> However, packing has a general meaning as well, when you want to group/cluster similar elements together.

The last paragraph in particular is a sign that the tag is ambiguous.

There's seven other tags with "packing" in their name, which suggests that correct terminology is important.

An example of a question tagged [packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packing) which isn't about structs in C is [Packing rectangular image data into a square texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263932/packing-rectangular-image-data-into-a-square-texture)

Comment: *since it may not memory-aligned* - missing a word there as well...

Comment: @JonClements an off-by-one error when talking about alignment? The irony!

Comment: Personally I think it should be removed (burniated?). For things relating to C I'd argue in using the C tag instead.